Having issues using Python + undetected_chromedriver executing after the cloudflare bot stop
I have some PYTHON 3.11 code that using undetected_chromedriver
while 1 == 1:
  timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
  showtime = timenow.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
  timetostart = timenow.strftime('%H:%M')
  print (showtime + "       " + timetostart + " -> " + runtime )
  if timetostart == runtime:
    break

element0 = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("id","ctl00_lower_panel_btnContinue")))
element0.click()

this works and gets me by the cloudflare bot detector clicking a button at a certain time
however I want to click another button that looks like this right after I am cleared by the CloudFlare bot detector
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$lower_panel$btnContinue" value="Confirm Application" onclick="revalidate(); return false;" id="ctl00_lower_panel_btnContinue" title="Confirm Application" class="btncontinue">

if I have this line after that first piece of code the cloudFlare bot stop will put up a checkbox instead of passing me through
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Confirm Application"]')))

any idea how to get this to "wait" and still not be detected as an automation?
